# Serilog ILogger Provider does not respond to configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I'm using Serilog as a provider for Microsoft.Extension.Logging, I don't want it to take over all logging control. However, Serilog is not responding to the configuration. I does not honor default levels neither default level for its own provider alias "Serilog".

Packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="1.0.1" />
```

Program.cs

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} - {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
        .WriteTo.Debug()
        .CreateLogger();

    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
        })
        .Build();
```

appsettings.json

```
 "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Serilog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please share a [MCVE]. Specifically we'd need to know what packages you've installed, and how you told it to read the configuration.

Comment: @mason Edited the question to add the relevant information.

Comment: I think your issue is that need to tell serilog to load from the configuration file the ConfigureLogging section there should be a `logging.ReadFrom.Configuration` call.

Comment: @asawyer Would that be Serilog configuration, not "ILogger" configuration? Skimming through Serilog.Extensions.Logging it seems it does not use "ILogger" configuration at all.

Answer (score -4):

The call `logging.AddSerilog(dispose: true);` also adds a filter with level Trace that overrides the Logging configuration. Add the Serilog Provider manually and configure Serilog with a minimum level Verbose, with this you can forget about the configuration of this horrible greedy library and use it just as any other Logging provider.

Program.cs

```
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging((builderContext, logging) =>
            {
                var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Level:w4} {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {SourceContext}]{NewLine}      {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                    .WriteTo.Debug(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {SourceContext} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                    .CreateLogger();
                logging.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, SerilogLoggerProvider>(services => new SerilogLoggerProvider(logger, true));
            })
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: Normally, self-answered questions elicit upvotes (I literally just upvoted [the Q and the A here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921743/there-are-no-logs-in-kibana-when-api-is-run-under-docker) - this does not. A well worded question can often get a great answer, but you're correct there are no guarantees. Something tells me you have plenty to offer around here in a positive sense; I'd beg you to go do that, and prove yourself wrong.